# Missing assembly reference—but I believe the package is properly referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

When I register the following `using` declaration:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI;
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'UI' type or namespace name does not exist in namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity' (missing an assembly reference?)

Everything looks right to me. I'm including a `<PackageReference>` to [the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI). But the error persists.

How do I troubleshoot this?

My `.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SQLite" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And my `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFrameworkAttribute("Bootstrap4")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyCompanyAttribute("ESporcum")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyConfigurationAttribute("Debug")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute("1.0.0")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyProductAttribute("ESporcum")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyTitleAttribute("ESporcum")]
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: Try deleting your `obj/` folder and doing another restore

Comment: Since your current project is core 3.0 version, but these dlls are 3.1 related version, try to update the version to be consistent and test again.

Answer (score 12):

In NuGet package

change this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI Ver.5.0.1
```

to:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI Ver.3.1.10
```